# unable to pass data through intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am launching an `Activity` from my `Application.java` file like this below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PinLoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("LockScreen", true);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is how I am receiving the value in the `Activity` in `onCreate()`:

```
lockScreen = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("LockScreen", false);
```

I am trying to pass a boolean value through `Intent` but I am not receiving any value through `Intent` in the `Activity`. I even checked `onNewIntent`. But I am not get any value.

Comment: Your code is working in my machine...Please check again after clean code

Comment: This is weird. Let me check @NikunjPatel

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is OK. Try rebuild or cleanup your project.

But I strongly recommend avoid using raw "string" as key for params. Use constant fields instead, e.g.:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public final static String LOCK_SCREEN_PARAM = "LockScreen";
    public static Intent getIntent (Context context, bool lockScreen){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(LOCK_SCREEN_PARAM, true);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        return intent;
    }

    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       lockScreen = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(LOCK_SCREEN_PARAM);
       ...
   }
}
```

And when you starting your activity:

```
startActivity(MyActivity.getIntent(getApplicationContext(), true));
```